# How to generate cryptographically random numbers?

Tags: php, random, cryptography, php-5.3, php-5.4

I want generate 5 digit number. 
the number will be used to verify phone numbers.

the random php functions doesn't use cryptographically strong algorithm, so I can't use them.

and openssl_random_pseudo_bytes generate also letters, I need just number .

How to do that ?

Comment: Use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes, convert that to hex, then convert the hex to an integer.

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes that's right, excuse me I have another question , does it safe to use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes  to generate long tokens that used to verify user sessions. ?

Comment: Five digit numbers cannot be cryptographically secure, they are too short.  There are only 99999 possible numbers, and that is small enough to crack by brute force.